# Install Vesta panel on LAMP droplet (Digital Ocean)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, control-panel, vesta

I have install and configured `Ubuntu` droplet with `LAMP` snapshot on the Digital Ocean service. Now I want to install `Vesta` panel. But looks like installation want's to reinstall Apache, MySQL, ...

```
Following software will be installed on your system:
   - Nginx frontend web server
   - Apache application web server
   - Bind DNS server
   - Exim mail server
   - Dovecot IMAP and POP3 server
   - MySQL database server
   - Vsftpd FTP server
```

But I have configured all of that, so how can I install Vesta in the right way?

I don't want to uninstall LAMP because all works now and configured!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before.

You should rebuild yor droplet with a fresh OS image

[image]

And do a fresh vesta install

https://vestacp.com/install/

I recommend you to use "advanced install setting"
Your command should look like this

[image]

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you can't.  Most hosting control panel software including Vesta, cPanel and Plesk must install their own versions of the daemons used to provide the services they manage.  They do this to ensure a known configuration across multiple distributions and to have control over the update process, preventing an update from the upstream provider from breaking their panel.